# Select top x of each id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a bit rusty with SQL.

Lets say I have `tblMachineLogs` with `MachineLogID`, `MachineID`, `LogTime (date+time)`.

This table is filled with logs from 10 machines with `MachineID` 1 to 10 and have lots of rows in it.

I want to select for example the last 5 log events but of each machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS do you use ?

Answer (score 7):

Use `Window Function` which will help you to find last `5` `log events` in each group`(MachineID)`

```
SELECT MachineLogID,
        MachineID,
        LogTime
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY MachineID ORDER BY LogTime DESC) Rn,
                MachineLogID,
                MachineID,
                LogTime
        FROM   tblMachineLogs) a
WHERE  rn <= 5
```

Comment: Now imagine that `tblMachineLogs` has millions or billions of rows and it has index on `(MachineID, LogTime DESC)`. Your solution with `ROW_NUMBER` would scan the whole table (or just the index, but it will be a full scan). If the index is on `(MachineID, LogTime ASC)` it would do an extra expensive sort as well. On the other hand, imagine that you have a tiny table `Machines` with 10 rows, one for each `MachineID`. How would you write the query to do 10 seeks on the index, instead of scanning the whole big table?

Comment: Cool story, @VladimirBaranov. If you have a better solution that satisfies the requirements and doesn't do the scan you've noted, post it as an answer.

Comment: @BenThul, I've added an answer comparing two solutions.

Comment: Bravo vova :), u are the best

Comment: @GuyCohen, we should not really be writing comments under another answer, but if you find my answer useful, you can upvote it, so it is closer to the top and more people have chance to see it in the future. Also, you can accept one of the answers to show to others what answer was the most useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for SQL Server. I tested it on SQL Server 2008.

Imagine that `MachineLogs` has millions or billions of rows and it has index on `(MachineID, LogTime DESC)`. Solution with `ROW_NUMBER` would scan the whole table (or just the index, but it will be a full scan). If the index is on `(MachineID, LogTime ASC)` it would do an extra expensive sort as well.

On the other hand, if we have a tiny table `Machines` with 10 rows, one for each `MachineID`, then it is possible to write a query that does 10 seeks on the index instead of scanning the whole big table.

I'll create a big table `MachineLogs` with 1 million rows and small table `Machines` with 10 rows and test two solutions.

Table `Machines` will have 10 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Machines](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Machines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Machines]
([ID])
VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
;
```

Big table with index on `([MachineID] ASC, [LogTime] DESC)`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MachineLogs](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MachineID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MachineLogs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MachineID_LogTime] ON [dbo].[MachineLogs]
(
    [MachineID] ASC,
    [LogTime] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MachineLogs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MachineLogs_Machines] FOREIGN KEY([MachineID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Machines] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MachineLogs] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MachineLogs_Machines]
GO
```

Generate 1M rows:

```
WITH
CTE_Times
AS
(
    -- generate 100,000 rows with random datetimes between 2001-01-01 and ~2004-03-01 (100,000,000 seconds)
    SELECT TOP(100000)
        DATEADD(second, 100000000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5), '20010101') AS LogTime
    FROM
        sys.all_objects AS X1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS X2
)
-- generate 1M rows
INSERT INTO dbo.MachineLogs
    (MachineID
    ,LogTime)
SELECT
    dbo.Machines.ID
    ,CTE_Times.LogTime
FROM
    dbo.Machines
    CROSS JOIN CTE_Times
;
```

### Solution with ROW_NUMBER

```
WITH
CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineID ORDER BY LogTime DESC) AS rn
        ,ID
        ,MachineID
        ,LogTime
    FROM MachineLogs
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,MachineID
    ,LogTime
FROM CTE_rn
WHERE rn <= 5
;
```

### Solution with CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT
    CA.ID
    ,CA.MachineID
    ,CA.LogTime
FROM
    Machines
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(5)
            MachineLogs.ID
            ,MachineLogs.MachineID
            ,MachineLogs.LogTime
        FROM MachineLogs
        WHERE
            MachineLogs.MachineID = Machines.ID
        ORDER BY LogTime DESC
    ) AS CA
;
```

### Execution plans

[image: plans]

You can see that solution with `ROW_NUMBER` does a index scan and solution with `CROSS APPLY` does index seek.

### IO statistics

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

Solution with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
(50 row(s) affected)
Table 'MachineLogs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2365, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Solution with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
(50 row(s) affected)
Table 'MachineLogs'. Scan count 10, logical reads 30, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Machines'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a query for each machine that selects the top 5 rows, union it all and sort by the log time in a descending order (to get the last 5).
Here is an example for two machines, just fill the missing 8.

```
--drop table #tmp
SELECT  *
into #tmp
FROM    
(
select 1 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.1 LogTime
    UNION
select 2 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE()- 0.2 LogTime
    UNION
select 3 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE()- 0.3 LogTime
    UNION
select 4 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE()- 0.4 LogTime
    UNION
select 5 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE()- 0.5 LogTime
    UNION
select 6 as MachineLogID, 1 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.6 LogTime
    UNION
select 7 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE()- 0.7 LogTime
    UNION
select 8 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.8 LogTime
    UNION
select 9 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.9 LogTime
    UNION
select 10 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.10 LogTime
    UNION
select 11 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.11 LogTime
    UNION
select 12 as MachineLogID, 2 as MachineID , GETDATE() - 0.12 LogTime
) a

SELECT  *
FROM    
(
    SELECT  top 5 *
    FROM  #tmp a
    where machineId = 1
    order by LogTime desc
        union
    SELECT  top 5 *
    FROM  #tmp a
    where machineId = 2
    order by LogTime desc
) a
order by a.machineId , a.LogTime desc
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I'd do it with an individual query per machine.

If you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT MachineLogID, MachineID, LogTime FROM tblMachineLogs WHERE MachineID='str_machineid' ORDER BY LogTime DESC LIMIT 5;
```

That would return the last 5 event log items from machine with ID indicated by `str_machineid`. Remove quotes if machine ID is a numeric field (and it should).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 5 * from yourTable where machineId =1
Union all
Select top 5 * from yourtable where machineid =2
Union all
.
.
.
.
Select top 5 * from yoyrtable 
Where machineid=10
```