# Return first product from database where repeating data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatasource

I am making an e-commerce site, and on the 'shop' page I want to show the lowest product price from my database for each unique productID.

So my data is as follows:

PRODUCT TABLE:

```
product ID (PK),
Product description,
yada yada
```

PRODUCT VARIANT:

```
ID (PK),
product Price,
product Stock,  
Size ID (PK),
```

PRODUCT SIZE:

```
Size ID (Pk),
Size
```

In practice, for each unique ID, I may have 2 or three product prices (based on size), so when I execute:

```sql
SELECT 
      ID, 
      productArtist, 
      productDescription, 
      ImageName, 
      ProductLP, 
      ProductPrice 
FROM tblProducts 
LEFT JOIN
tblProductVariant ON tblProducts.ID = tblProductVariant.productID
LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
```

I get the same product showing 2 or three times, with each individual price, I only want to display one product result with the lowest price, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ranking function to order the rows by price and then select the first row.  Even if there are ties, you'll only get one row. This approach also gives you the ability to choose the top or bottom n rows by sorting in either descending or ascending order and setting the Row_Id to the number of rows you want. (e.g. Where Row_Id < 6 would give you the top 5 rows)

```
SELECT  ID, 
        productArtist, 
        productDescription, 
        ImageName, 
        ProductLP, 
        ProductPrice 
FROM (    SELECT 
              ID, 
              productArtist, 
              productDescription, 
              ImageName, 
              ProductLP, 
              ProductPrice 
              Row_Id = ROW_Number() OVER (Partition By tblProducts.ProductId ORDER BY tblProducts.ProductId, ProductPrice asc) 
        FROM tblProducts 
        LEFT JOIN
        tblProductVariant ON tblProducts.ID = tblProductVariant.productID
        LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
    ) QRY

WHERE Row_Id = 1
```

Comment: As I've demonstrated in a recent another very similar question, it can be more efficient to use `CROSS APPLY`, rather than `ROW_NUMBER`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313651/select-top-x-of-each-id/28333355#28333355

Comment: Actually, you should `ORDER BY ProductPrice asc, ProductVariant.ID` instead of `ORDER BY tblProducts.ProductId, ProductPrice asc`. We want to order by price first, and only if there are several variants of a product with the same price, then resolve the tie and produce consistent results by using the ProductVariant ID or Stock or Size, or something else, whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You only want the rows where the price = the `MIN(ProductPrice)` for the product?

```
SELECT ID, productArtist, productDescription, ImageName, ProductLP, ProductPrice
FROM tblProducts 
LEFT JOIN tblProductVariant as PV1 ON tblProducts.ID = tblProductVariant.productID
LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
WHERE ProductPrice = (
    SELECT MIN(ProductPrice)
    FROM  tblProductVariant as PV2 
    LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
    where PV2.productID = PV1.productID 
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Turophile , I was getting a 'could not be bound' error. I removed the PV1 identity which has now worked;
`SELECT ID, productArtist, productDescription, ImageName, ProductLP, ProductPrice
FROM tblProducts 
LEFT JOIN tblProductVariant ON tblProducts.ID = tblProductVariant.productID
LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
WHERE ProductPrice = (
    SELECT MIN(ProductPrice)
    FROM  tblProductVariant as PV2 
    LEFT JOIN tblProductSize ON tblProductSize.szeID = tblProductVariant.sizeID
    where PV2.productID = tblProductVariant.productID 
) `

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I didn't have the opportunity to test it but thought it would be close enough to get you there.

Comment: This approach will give you all of the rows that exist at the lowest price, not just one. I think the OP wants  to see just one row.

Comment: @DataWriter True, but it seems a reasonable assumption that there would only be one product size / variant with a lowest price. If this is not the case, the question should be revised to completely specify the requirements. You cannot assume that the row with the lowest (or highest) rowid is the correct one. In fact, using rowid could make the result appear "random".

Comment: I agree that the question is a bit vague, but I don't see how Row_Id()  could return an incorrect or random row. The PARTITION BY sequences the set of rows for *each* Product_Id into a series from 1 to n. The ORDER BY Product_Id, Price asc sorts prices within those sets  from low to high. Even in the case of ties, the lowest price is row 1.  Why do you think it would return an incorrect or random result?

Comment: @DataWriter I didn't mean incorrect. I meant you don't know which of the rows you will get (which may not matter for this particular problem). From the manual at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx:  _There is no guarantee that the rows returned by a query using ROW_NUMBER() will be ordered exactly the same with each execution unless the following conditions are true.
Values of the partitioned column are unique.
Values of the ORDER BY columns are unique.
Combinations of values of the partition column and ORDER BY columns are unique._

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you got fairly close to the answer yourself.

```
select  P.ID, P.Artist, P.Description, P.Price, S.Size
from    tblProducts  P
join    tblProductVariant PV
    on  PV.ID = P.ID
left join tblProductVariant PV2
    on  PV2.ID    = PV.ID
    end PV2.Price < PV.Price
join    tblSize      S
    on  S.ID = PV.ID
where   PV2.ID is null;
```

Notice that the left join will result in PV2 fields being NULLed out whenever there is a product id match but there were no prices lower than the one in the PV row. These are the ones you want as that is the lowest price for that product. So in the `where` clause, filter out all the others. Thus your result will be only the products of each ID that is the lowest price.

May I add a couple of pieces of advice? Thank you. First of all, always alias your tables and use that alias in every field reference. The computer doesn't need this if a field name of a table is unique to that table, but do it for the developers who come behind you and even yourself during development and when you work on the query months or years later. It's a simple way to increase the maintainability of your code with absolutely no impact on the execution of the code.

Also (and you probably have no control over this -- sorry) don't prefix table and view names with "tbl", "t_" or "vw_" or anything that says "Hey, dummy! This is a table, you twit!" It can be alright as sample code used for illustration (*how to* queries, generally when no actual tables exist), but for a real-life databases -- whether production, test, qa or whatever) it reeks of amateurishness. It points out that the database, or this part of it, was designed by database programmers (junior ones at that) who saw this convention used in some text books rather than an actual data architect or modeler. This practice does *not* increase maintainability or really provide any benefit at all. It does, however, break any wall of abstraction that could be built between the data and the developers who write the apps using that data.`</soap_box>`